# PHP Save an Image to a Server?

Tags: php, flash, image, actionscript

I'm having a stump with some PHP...

I have a Flash Application that sends an image (using as3corelib) to a PHP script that previews it in the browser, which works! But, I would actually like it to permanently save it the a server folder (uploads, etc.) instead of temporarily saving it. I can't find the right variable in the PHP that actually sends the image to a server so it could save it.

```
<?php

    switch ($_POST["format"]) {
        case 'jpg':
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            break;

        case 'png':
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
            break;
    }

    if ($_POST['action'] == 'prompt') {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $_POST['fileName']);
    }

    echo base64_decode($_POST["image"]);

?>
```

Here's an example of it: http://shmoggo.com/snapshot
JPEG, Open to Browser (but I would like it to SAVE to browser)

Any PHP guru help would be terrific, thanks a lot!

Aaron

Comment: Usually PHP stores the upload file data in $_FILES, try var_dump($_FILES) to see if it has the data. [php upload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the filename, you can simply do

```
 $newpath = "/folders/image.jpg";
 $data = file_get_contents($_POST['fileName']);
 file_put_contents($newpath, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks perfect, but I can't get it to work for the life of me! It saves a blank "image.jpg" with no data... any thoughts?

Comment: is $_POST['fileName'] the actual filename of the image on the remote server and not some local path right?  Maybe if $_POST["image"] already has the actual data you can file_put_contents with that as the data... you may have to base64_decode though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then displaying it, save `$_POST['image']` to the server, see **[File System](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php)**